# Should we create Java source code and Junit test as different project in java like they do in .Net?

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

In Java, I have seen the practice of having test and source in the same project inside different packages. But now someone asked me to make Java source code as a different project and Take test out of the main project and make it a separate Test project like in .net and give the reference of that source jar in the project.

See Following is the practice in general we follow

> src>>main>>java>>com>>foo>>Sample.java
>
> test>>main>>java>>com>>foo>>SampleTest.java

But now someone asked me to create a project

> src>>main>>java>>com>>foo>>Sample.java

as one project and then make Test like a Java project give reference of the above jar into your test project(add that jar into libs or add a dependency into your build file) to execute test cases.

> test>>main>>java>>com>>foo>>SampleTest.java

Do you think that is a feasible solution?

Should we follow such kind of practice.?

Comment: so much convoluted.

Comment: Definitely. Actually having code and test in the same project ends up with unnecessary tests in the final jar.

Comment: You don't know how to build a jar that won't include the test package?

Comment: The build tool is Gradle.  After the build, the jar is created and that jar don't contain any test cases. As the build file is containing JUnit dependency is used by the application while the build is happening to test cases get executed. In final jar dependency of JUNIT is not available and no JUnit test cases. To remove that dependency someone suggested to make two separate projects and remove the dependency of JUnit. So according to me its not good practice to make different projects one will contain source and one will contain test cases.

Comment: @ Erwin Smout: I know how to build a jar without including a test package. In general, we use JUnit dependency in build file to execute test cases.  The build tool is Gradle. After the build, the jar is created and that jar don't contain any test cases. As the build file is containing JUnit dependency is used by the application while the build is happening to test cases get executed. In final jar dependency of JUNIT is not available and no JUnit test cases.  For more information please check above my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention Java, it is a usual practice for Java based projects to have Junit tests in the same project(maven/gradle). Your source and test code structure would look like this:

```
src
│  
── main
     └── java
         └── com
              └── foo
│                 ├──Sample.java
│     
│       
└── test
     └── java
          └── com
               └── foo
                   └── SampleTest.java
```

With source and junit in the same project, you will be able to relate to the code and unit tests much better. This approach allows the tests to access to all the public and package visible methods of the classes under test.

This is also part of a standard maven/gradle directory layout where the project is the same but folder is separate.

A common set of integration or functional tests can exist in a separate project depending on the requirement.

You can also refer to [Junit FAQ](https://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#organize_1) which talks about organizing tests.

Keep it simple, you could get started by keeping unit tests in same project and think of separating it if really needed.

Comment: Ok.  As per your comment  "A common set of integration or functional tests can exist in a separate project depending on the requirement."   But this will be helpful for selenium and not for Junit right?

Comment: Yes. To clarify the " A common set of integration or functional tests being in a separate project "- This is where you have "many" projects and want to separate out only "common" integration/functional tests. Sometimes, if it is simple enough, each project can have it's own integration test and junit test. The integration test can be under a separate folder.